# Remove a contentView from NativeActivity

Tags: android, surfaceview, native-activity

What is the correct (or any) way to remove a view that has been set using setContentView.  The application is basically a NativeActivity application that uses openGL and as such has no layouts/views defined.  I needed to add a splash screen very early on and so from java create a class derived from SurfaceView to display a resource image.  This all works fine and I set the SurfaceView using

```
    mySurfaceView = new SplashScreen(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(mySurfaceView);
```

The problem is i dont seem to be able to remove this view to see my openGl application.  I can hear the audio and it seems to be running, but this splash screen is topmost.  Ive tried setting visibility, using setContnetView(null), setting a basic blank textview instead, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Comment: it will remove all view and you can setContentView again ((ViewGroup) context.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).removeAllViews();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setcontentview can be called only once in a activity. You can try to setcontentview in if-else condition but it can be done only once and only in oncreate.

Comment: So its not possible to make it go away to show the openGL once its set?  Is it possible to send it to the back or something?

Comment: why not start a new activity after say 3 seconds and finish the splash activity that is how most of us display a splash screen. Also during those 3 seconds do some useful work

Comment: I guess its because its something being added afterwards so it would involve alot of moving around, but i can give it a go :)

Comment: its not true ! setContentView can call more than once

Answer (score 0):

There's no `unsetContentView()`. Use `Fragment` for your splash screen content and have your `SurfaceView` there. Add it from code and then remove when done. Or just have set `View.GONE` visibility on your splash `SurfaceView`